# How to create an alert with strategy.entry function without taking any entry with that signal in Pinescript Strategy?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, cryptocurrency, tradingview-api

I am making a strategy which gives Long signal when it break the previous day high. In this strategy there are two signal alert.

Firstly : (Get Ready For Long ) - This signal will come when price the very close to the breakout level.

Secondly : (Long) - When the price close above the breakout level then it will give a Long signal.

But problem is that, I need to use strategy.entry function for creating "Get Ready for Long" signal . Because in strategy version there is no other way to set alert. I don't need to enter on this signal because it just an warning before the breakout.
I need to take entry on the "Long" signal only.

So right now how can I add alert on the "Get Ready for Long" signal without taking any entry trigger and how to set entry on "Long" signal only? (Like the screenshot below)[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Albqd.png)

Comment: You can use `alert` function in Pine strategies too. Here is more info https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Alerts.html#in-strategies

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.